# Read any file and packed file in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem.
I have a text file "hello.pdf"
I put the file to the resource of the project and read the file

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\vivio\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\STool\STool\Resources\hello.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

I have a question: If I want packet STool to STool.exe, and then install this packet in the (D:)disk then I think I will not read file hello.pdf because in the code I set `pathfile` is `"C:\Users\vivio\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\STool\STool\Resources\hello.pdf"`
Help me to resolve this problem, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The following link is same with yours, maybe it would be helpful.

[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Or this one.
[How to open a PDF file that is also a project resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609476/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-that-is-also-a-project-resource)

Answer (score 0):

First, copy the file to your project directory and include it in your project. In the file's properties, set the Copy to Output Directory to **Copy Always**. Now it will always copy to the build directory when you compile.

It will be saved to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, so to reference the file you will always be able to use:

```
string filename = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Resources\\hello.pdf";
```

[image: Make sure the copy to output directory property is set to **Copy Always**]